# jquery ui dialog custom buttons

Tags: jquery-ui

Is there a way to use my own custome button style in the jquery ui dialog widget? I have tried all possible ways, including some suggested on the site here, all to no avail... Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest and easiest way to define your own style is to use the [jQuery UI Themeroller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) to create a custom theme (or just modify an existing one). All jQuery UI widgets will use the theme you declare.

**Edit:** [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/N29Zg/) of modified button style only.

Comment: Yeah, I used that but it still doesn't allow me to tweak the buttons only!

Comment: No, I guess the themeroller itself doesn't, but you could just style the button class itself. I have added an example fiddle.

Comment: Thanks, Andy. I'm afraid I still can't change things like the background color of the button, radius, etc...

Comment: No problem. You need to add `background:green !important;` on the same  `button.ui-button` rule. The problem you are seeing in this case is that the jQuery UI theme declares the color as part of the `background` rule, whereas your `background-color` (even with `!important`) is less important so the jQuery background was still taking precedence.

Answer (score 4):

Thats how I handled my custom buttons on jquery UI dialog box :

```
        $('#dialog').dialog({
            height: 300, 
            width: 600, 
            modal: true, 
            resizable: false, 
            create: function(event, ui) { 
                $("#done").click(function(event) {
                    $('#dialog').dialog('close');
            })}
        });
```

Where 'done' is ID of my button element and 'dialog' is id of my div acting as dialog box.